# How can I make my Socket on throughout the program and pass value through it

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, tcpclient

Here I created a socket that I want to make global and pass the integer value throught the socket by clicking the button.But I am getting Error when I try to make Socket global.So how can make the Socket global,and pass the integer value through it. how can make the Socket global,and pass the integer value through it.how can make the Socket global,and pass the integer value through it.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button buttonOn;
Button button1;

Socket socket;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ON);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    try {
        System.out.println("HIIIII");
        socket = new Socket("198.168.0.79",8888);
        socket.getKeepAlive();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = 2;
            bhari b = new bhari();
            b.execute(String.valueOf(temp));

        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int temp = 1;
            String fan = String.valueOf(temp);
            bhari b = new bhari();
            b.execute(fan);

        }
      });
    }
  }
```

class bhari:

```
    class bhari extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Integer>{
     Socket socket;
   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {


          String massage = params[0];
    try {


        if(socket== null){

            System.out.println("if");
            socket = new Socket("192.168.0.79",8888);
            socket.getKeepAlive();
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(massage));
            dataOutputStream.flush();
           // dataOutputStream.close();


        }else {
            System.out.println("Else");

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(massage));
            dataOutputStream.flush();
           // dataOutputStream.close();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("End");
    return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are creating another socket object inside of asynctask..
if you want to use same socket object you will have to pass it to asynctask too.
its Another solution is that you pass your integer value to asynctask but create socket only inside of asynctask

Comment: But How can it possible.As I am new in android proggraming.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a singleton

```
class Mysocket{
private static Socket socket;

public static Socket getInstance()
{
if(socket==null)
{
   socket = new Socket("192.168.0.79",8888);
        socket.getKeepAlive();
}
return socket;
}


}
```

Comment: `socket.getKeepAlive()` does what that iis useful here exactly?

Comment: No, If you just want a socket connection object then remove the line.